# Android:state_hovered not working

Tags: android

I have a simple button, and I am trying to make it change color when you hover over it. I am using an android simulator on eclipse but the android:state_hovered="true" is not working.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

I already have this code, can I make it work with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/darkish_blue"
                android:startColor="@color/darkish_blue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:endColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="false" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:startColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/medium_blue"
                android:startColor="@color/medium_blue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

The pressed state is working but selected and hover don't work,.

Comment: you can also try this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Hover.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **selector** selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Set the **background** of button

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```